# Get and update data in one query Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
    $wor= Warehouse_other_receive::where('or_no', $id)->first();
    Warehouse_other_receive_detail::where('or_no', $id)->update(array('or_date'=>$wor->or_date);
    $wor->update(['status' => '1']);
```

My goal is to get data and update it in one query in my Laravel project. On the first-line I get data from `wharehouse_other_receive` model, on the second line update data form first line get data the third line is after second-line code update `Warehouse_other_receive model`

Comment: okay! you did what u've said ! then ? what is the question ? be specific

Comment: this query looks wrong.. just do dd($wor) and see what's coming.

Comment: from where you are getting `$wor->or_date`